# Iterate over String Arrays inside ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to iterate over string arrays inside a ArrayList. How is this possible?

```
public ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

// [ [12, "Something"], [6, "Thing"], [3, "Cookies"] ]

public void getText(final List arrayList) {
  for (String[] array : arrayList) {
    Log.d("Text", array[1]);
  }
}
```

Error (line 4)

- Required: String[]
- Found: Object

Comment: `Log.d("Text", array);` gives you a `String[]`, while your `Log.d("Text", array[1]);` gives you a `String`

Comment: @Pphoenix It's the same thing I wrote, what are you talking about?

Comment: You have something in angle brackets on your `ArrayList`, what does it do? Why are there no angle brackets on the `List` in the method signature?

Comment: In short - read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/2071828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You did not specified the actual type of data which your List into `getText` method is going to take. You need to replace `final List arrayList` with `final List<String[]> arrayList` into `getText()`*

```
public void getText(final List<String[]> arrayList) {
  for (String[] array : arrayList) {
    Log.d("Text", array[1]);
  }
}
```

---

*You should read [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it/2770692).*

Comment: While correct, code only answers are discouraged - and you should know that. Please add an explanation of what the problem was and how you have fixed it.

Comment: @PankajKumar Thank you so much! I'm gonna make this answer correct when the time expires. You are a hero!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you are trying to use an ArrayList when just a good old String Array by itself will do the trick. I certainly understand ArrayLists are great tools, but it seems unnecessary here without more context.

Just iterate over the String array as follows:

```
String[] array = yourInputSourceHere;

for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
     Log.d("Text", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm using ArrayList because their size isn't fixed. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

To Make use of For each loop do the following

```
for (String array:arraylist)

{
// use Array as one String object
System.out.println(array);
}
```